# Form data not reaching my database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to PHP and am trying to enter contact details via a form. I have put together the following code taking info from a form and storing it to a database. This code is based on a couple of tutorials. The first code works, but I am unsure about security/sql injection here. The second method is the PDO method. I am not getting any error message but the table is not updating. Which method is best and any pointers on why no insert on PDO appreciated. The form

```
<form action="contactForm.php" method="post">
    <p>Name: <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="60"></p>
    <p>Email address: <input name="email" type="email" id="email" size="40"></p>
    <p>Phone: <input name="phone" type="tel" id="phone" size="40"></p>
    <p>Twitter: <input name="twitter" type="text" id="twitter" size="40"></p>
    <p>Comment:</p>
    <p><textarea name="comment" cols="55" rows="5"id="comment"></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

the first method

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    define('DB_NAME','users');
    define('DB_USER','root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD','');
    define('DB_HOST','localhost');

    $conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

    if(!$conn){
        die('Sorry, we could not connect at this time:'.mysql_error());
    }

    $db_selected=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $conn);

    if(!$db_selected){
        die('Cannot use'.DB_NAME.':'.mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("users", $conn);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO usercontacts (name, email, phone, twitter, comment) VALUES ('$_POST[name]',               '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[phone]', '$_POST[twitter]', '$_POST[comment]')";

    mysql_query($sql,$conn);

    mysql_close($conn);

}
```

and the PDO method

```
$dbname = 'users';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpassword = '';
$dbhost = 'localhost'; 

try{
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname'.$dbname,$dbuser, $dbpassword);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name= $_POST['name'];
    $email= $_POST['email'];
    $phone= $_POST['phone'];
    $twitter= $_POST['twitter'];
    $comment= $_POST['comment'];

    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO usercontacts (name, email, phone, twitter, comment) VALUES (:name, :email, :phone, :twitter, :comment)");
    $query->bindValue(':name',$name);
    $query->bindValue(':email',$email);
    $query->bindValue(':phone',$phone);
    $query->bindValue(':twitter',$twitter);
    $query->bindValue(':comment',$comment);
    $query->execute();
}
```

Comment: any error messages you are getting?

Comment: None on the PDO method. Maybe I am not looking for error message correctly?

Comment: This `catch(PDOException $e){ echo mysql_error();
}` you can't use `mysql_error()` with PDO. Use `print $e->getMessage();`

Comment: Sorry that should have read echo $e->getMessage(); I will edit.

Comment: might sound silly.. but did you pass a value for name? 'if(isset($_POST['name'])){'

Comment: I was just about to say, we could do with seeing your form code to see what is actually being passed

Comment: I have added form code.

Comment: Instead of `if(isset($_POST['name'])){` do like you did for your first method `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`

Comment: You may also have a quotes issue with your PDO connection syntax. Try `$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpassword);`

Comment: Tried that, but no joy.

Comment: Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, see if it yields anything. Meaning, right under `$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname'.$dbname,$dbuser, $dbpassword);`

Comment: Yes that brought an error message number 1046  No database selected' in C:\wamp\www\contactForm.php on line 64 - that's the execute(); line

Comment: *"No database selected"* - Well there you go ;-) you've just debugged your error.

Comment: You need to use `dbname=$dbname"` as in `$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpassword);` and not `dbname'.$dbname`

Comment: OK got it, thanks Fred. I was missing an equals sign setting up the $db. Thanks for the help. Is this method secure?

Comment: You're welcome and yes it is (safe) since you are using colon placeholders `:` instead of variables `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an error here:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname'.$dbname,$dbuser, $dbpassword);
```

it should be:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';port=3306; dbname='.$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
```

Comment: I think port 3306 is the default. Adding it in the answer makes it harder to see what the actual solution is -- he just had a typo and was missing an `=`.